# Scroll bar on body wrapper but not body

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a scroll bar on my inner-body wrapper, instead of the body itself:

**CSS**

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#body_wrap {
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body class="index"><div id="body_wrap">

    <!-- Content with big height -->

</div> </body>
```

The content overflows (ie: if I strip all style there are vertical scrollbars). But with the above styling I don't get any scrollbars. I would expet the result to be similar in both cases at the moment, as the `#body_wrap` wraps the whole content. Yet I get no scrollbars on `#body_wrap`.

**How can I hide the scrollbars from body and have them on the child wrapper instead?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using a percentage height on `#body_wrap`, you'll need a height on `<html>` and `<body>` to which it will be relative. Without it, you're calculating 100% of undefined.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#body_wrap {
  font-size: 30px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="body_wrap">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Morbi commodo, ipsum sed pharetra gravida, orci magna rhoncus neque, id pulvinar odio lorem non turpis. Nullam sit amet enim. Suspendisse id velit vitae ligula volutpat condimentum. Aliquam erat
  volutpat. Sed quis velit. Nulla facilisi. Nulla libero. Vivamus pharetra posuere sapien. Nam consectetuer. Sed aliquam, nunc eget euismod ullamcorper, lectus nunc ullamcorper orci, fermentum bibendum enim nibh eget ipsum. Donec porttitor ligula eu dolor.
  Maecenas vitae nulla consequat libero cursus venenatis. Nam magna enim, accumsan eu, blandit sed, blandit a, eros. Quisque facilisis erat a dui. Nam malesuada ornare dolor. Cras gravida, diam sit amet rhoncus ornare, erat elit consectetuer erat, id
  egestas pede nibh eget odio. Proin tincidunt, velit vel porta elementum, magna diam molestie sapien, non aliquet massa pede eu diam. Aliquam iaculis. Fusce et ipsum et nulla tristique facilisis. Donec eget sem sit amet ligula viverra gravida. Etiam
  vehicula urna vel turpis. Suspendisse sagittis ante a urna. Morbi a est quis orci consequat rutrum. Nullam egestas feugiat felis. Integer adipiscing semper ligula. Nunc molestie, nisl sit amet cursus convallis, sapien lectus pretium metus, vitae pretium
  enim wisi id lectus. Donec vestibulum. Etiam vel nibh. Nulla facilisi. Mauris pharetra. Donec augue. Fusce ultrices, neque id dignissim ultrices, tellus mauris dictum elit, vel lacinia enim metus eu nunc. Proin at eros non eros adipiscing mollis. Donec
  semper turpis sed diam. Sed consequat ligula nec tortor. Integer eget sem. Ut vitae enim eu est vehicula gravida. Morbi ipsum ipsum, porta nec, tempor id, auctor vitae, purus. Pellentesque neque. Nulla luctus erat vitae libero. Integer nec enim. Phasellus
  aliquam enim et tortor. Quisque aliquet, quam elementum condimentum feugiat, tellus odio consectetuer wisi, vel nonummy sem neque in elit. Curabitur eleifend wisi iaculis ipsum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames
  ac turpis egestas. In non velit non ligula laoreet ultrices. Praesent ultricies facilisis nisl. Vivamus luctus elit sit amet mi. Phasellus pellentesque, erat eget elementum volutpat, dolor nisl porta neque, vitae sodales ipsum nibh in ligula. Maecenas
  mattis pulvinar diam. Curabitur sed leo. Nulla facilisi. In vel sem. Morbi id urna in diam dignissim feugiat. Proin molestie tortor eu velit. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam ultrices, diam tempus vulputate egestas, eros pede varius leo, sed imperdiet
  lectus est ornare odio. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Proin consectetuer velit in dui. Phasellus wisi purus, interdum vitae, rutrum accumsan, viverra in, velit. Sed enim risus, congue non, tristique in, commodo eu, metus.
  Aenean tortor mi, imperdiet id, gravida eu, posuere eu, felis. Mauris sollicitudin, turpis in hendrerit sodales, lectus ipsum pellentesque ligula, sit amet scelerisque urna nibh ut arcu. Aliquam in lacus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci
  luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nulla placerat aliquam wisi. Mauris viverra odio. Quisque fermentum pulvinar odio. Proin posuere est vitae ligula. Etiam euismod. Cras a eros. Nunc auctor bibendum eros. Maecenas porta accumsan mauris. Etiam
  enim enim, elementum sed, bibendum quis, rhoncus non, metus. Fusce neque dolor, adipiscing sed, consectetuer et, lacinia sit amet, quam. Suspendisse wisi quam, consectetuer in, blandit sed, suscipit eu, eros. Etiam ligula enim, tempor ut, blandit nec,
  mollis eu, lectus. Nam cursus. Vivamus iaculis. Aenean risus purus, pharetra in, blandit quis, gravida a, turpis. Donec nisl. Aenean eget mi. Fusce mattis est id diam. Phasellus faucibus interdum sapien. Duis quis nunc. Sed enim. Pellentesque vel dui
  sed orci faucibus iaculis. Suspendisse dictum magna id purus tincidunt rutrum. Nulla congue. Vivamus sit amet lorem posuere dui vulputate ornare. Phasellus mattis sollicitudin ligula. Duis dignissim felis et urna. Integer adipiscing congue metus. Nam
  pede. Etiam non wisi. Sed accumsan dolor ac augue. Pellentesque eget lectus. Aliquam nec dolor nec tellus ornare venenatis. Nullam blandit placerat sem. Curabitur quis ipsum. Mauris nisl tellus, aliquet eu, suscipit eu, ullamcorper quis, magna. Mauris
  elementum, pede at sodales vestibulum, nulla tortor congue massa, quis pellentesque odio dui id est. Cras faucibus augue. Suspendisse vestibulum dignissim quam. Integer vel augue. Phasellus nulla purus, interdum ac, venenatis non, varius rutrum, leo.
  Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Duis a eros. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos hymenaeos. Fusce magna mi, porttitor quis, convallis eget, sodales
  ac, urna. Phasellus luctus venenatis magna. Vivamus eget lacus. Nunc tincidunt convallis tortor. Duis eros mi, dictum vel, fringilla sit amet, fermentum id, sem. Phasellus nunc enim, faucibus ut, laoreet in, consequat id, metus. Vivamus dignissim. Cras
  lobortis tempor velit. Phasellus nec diam ac nisl lacinia tristique. Nullam nec metus id mi dictum dignissim. Nullam quis wisi non sem lobortis condimentum. Phasellus pulvinar, nulla non aliquam eleifend, tortor wisi scelerisque felis, in sollicitudin
  arcu ante lacinia leo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies
  mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi.
</div>
```

[View on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fG883/1/)